# facebook sdk crashes in application delegate

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Here's how I replicate the bug. So here's the code I have for logging in:

```
@IBAction func FBLoginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.browser
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            return
        }
    }
 }
```

If i login twice, and then run the app again, this line crashes in the appdelegate.

```
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

If i only log in once, and run the app again, no crash happens. The full stack for the crash is the following:

> 2016-12-09 10:51:28.893 Persistence[73125:897290]
>   -[NSConcreteMutableData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000004ec40 2016-12-09 10:51:28.903
>   Persistence[73125:897290] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSConcreteMutableData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x60000004ec40'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001085e634b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000107c2a21e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000108655f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010856bc15
>   ___forwarding_** + 1013   4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010856b798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   FBSDKCoreKit
>   0x000000010700aa5a -[FBSDKAccessTokenCacheV4 fetchAccessToken] + 202
>     6   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010700902c
>   -[FBSDKAccessTokenCache fetchAccessToken] + 92    7   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x0000000107017d2d -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 125     8   Persistence
>   0x000000010572bcb7
>   _TFC11Persistence11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryVSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyP____Sb
>   + 727     9   Persistence                         0x000000010572cfb4 _TToFC11Persistence11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryVSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyP____Sb
>   + 180     10  UIKit                               0x00000001091110be -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290     11  UIKit                               0x0000000109112a43
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236   12  UIKit                               0x0000000109118de9
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731   13  UIKit                               0x0000000109115f69
>   -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d698723
>   **FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24     15  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d69859c
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189  16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d698925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010858b311
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010857059c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010856fa86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918     20  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010856f494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     21  UIKit
>   0x00000001091147e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434    22  UIKit
>   0x000000010911a964 UIApplicationMain + 159    23  Persistence
>   0x000000010572d97f main + 111     24  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010b3a368d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I reverted to version 4.17.0 of the Facebook SDK and I no longer get the crash.

Comment: I'm getting the same crash. just to confirm, the crashing version is 4.18.0?

Comment: This is ridiculous. Thanks for the solution anyways, hopefully Facebook will release an up-to-date Swift-based SDK with full functionality...

Comment: Seems fixed in 4.19.0

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 4.18.0 of the Facebook SDK, then update it to 4.19.0 or to the current version and you won't get the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no restricted versions of `FBSDK` in your `Podfile`, like so:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

Then do the `pod update`. Don't put a `--no-repo-update` to let your local specs repos be updated.

Latest local specs repositories will let you be able to download the latest version of `FBSDK`, which is the `4.19.0`.