# App crashes when Simulator is restarted

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I started using facebook SDK and the official [react native wrapper](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk).
Am not sure if this is the cause or if its my usage of AsyncStorage. But whenever I quit the simulator and then re-run my app via (`react-native run-ios`), the app crashes. Everytime I have to "Reset content and settings" for it to go away. Below is the logs I can find.

```
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Error>: assertion failed: 15G1108 14A345: libxpc.dylib + 62597 [37A9DF49-35C1-3D93-B854-B35CACF0100F]: 0x7d
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 Unknown[22405] <Error>:
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Error>: [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
--- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Notice>: Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x6100001971b0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6080000b9620>, executor: RCTJSCExecutor)
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Warning>: Class GenericShare was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Warning>: Class WhatsAppShare was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Warning>: Class GooglePlusShare was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Error>: [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Warning>: Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Error>: -[NSConcreteMutableData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000050710
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 XXXXX[22405] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000050710'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020c834b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000100fd821e objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102137f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010204dc15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010204d798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
        5   XXXXX                            0x0000000100657170 -[FBSDKAccessTokenCacheV4 fetchAccessToken] + 179
        6   XXXXX                            0x0000000100642526 -[FBSDKAccessTokenCache fetchAccessToken] + 73
        7   XXXXX                            0x000000010064cfbb -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 97
        8   XXXXX                            0x00000001004c7552 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 898
        9   UIKit                               0x000000010476768e -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
        10  UIKit                               0x0000000104769013 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
        11  UIKit                               0x000000010476f3b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
        12  UIKit                               0x000000010476c539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
        13  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107bf176b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
        14  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107bf15e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
        15  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107bf196d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010206d311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010205259c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102051a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102051494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
        20  UIKit                               0x000000010476adb6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
        21  UIKit                               0x0000000104770f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
        22  XXXXX                            0x00000001004c788f main + 111
        23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010613b68d start + 1
    )
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 SpringBoard[22278] <Error>: [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.B70B2265-1548-4811-B873-564E3E5DAFCB.launchd_sim[22261] (UIKitApplication:org.reactjs.native.example.XXXXX[0xe405][22405]) <Notice>: Service exited due to Abort trap: 6
Dec 10 21:48:34 sseshac-in-la-2 assertiond[22282] <Warning>: notify_suspend_pid() failed with error 7
```

Comment: Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?

Comment: Sorry, I am not conversant with RN internals. Could you elaborate ? This was all working since before I introduced facebook sdk and asyncstorage.

Comment: Just a stupid joke, sorry.

Comment: Have you linked proper version of Facebook SDK?

Comment: You might want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064234/facebook-sdk-crashes-in-application-delegate

Comment: @Arjuna: I have used the latest 4.18 version of SDK. My crashes are only when I have quit and restarted simulator, Otherwise when the app is running (After I have reset content and settings), it works just fine

Comment: @s Are you checking if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) before calling login method? In the link that I mentioned above he said that it is crashing when he tries to login second time. So are you checking whether he is already logged in before calling login again?

Comment: I am running into the same problem. Did you figure out why it's happening for you?